# I don't understand the regular expression in make file

Tags: makefile

I have a make file, which has the following lines:

```
EXECUTABLE = $(ONLINE_HOME)/bin/sec2ici   
OBJECTS = $(ONLINE_HOME)/src/dte_mq.o \    
     $(ONLINE_HOME)/src/sec2ici.o    

ALLINCL    =    -I$(ONLINE_HOME)/inc -I$(MQM_HOME)/inc -I$(ORACLE_HOME)/rdbms/public    

MQLIB =   -L${MQM_HOME}/lib64 -lmqm -lmqmcs -lmqmzse   
MYLIB =    

ORALIB = -L${ORACLE_HOME}/lib/ -lclntsh    

ALLLIB     =     $(MQLIB) \    
     $(ORALIB) \    
     $(MYLIB) \    
     -lnsl -ldl    

CFLAGS     =    -g \    
    $(ALLINCL)    


all: $(EXECUTABLE)    

COMPILE.c =  $(CC)  $(CFLAGS)    

.SUFFIXES:   .o

.c.o:
    $(COMPILE.c) -c $*.c -o ${<:.c=.o}
```

Could you please explain to me what the regular expression after $(COMPILE.c) means?

Also, where is the rule which gets only four necessary files out of 20 in the `src` directory?

Comment: there's no reqular expression

Comment: My guess: grab all C files and compile them to O file with the same name as C file just different extension.

Comment: I am not sure this thing actually works. `$*` is whatever was matched by `%` in the pattern, but this rule doesn't have `%`.

Comment: @aragaer it works, `.c.o:` is an old style pattern rule equivalent to `%.o: %.c`

Comment: What **specifically** do you not understand? What did you not find in the documentation of make? Did you check the tutorials?

Comment: the problem is that this make file compiles special program, like sec2dte_mq.c, sec2dte_2ici.c,adt.c,dte_mq.c, which are on the same directory with many other files and I don't understand, how it takes only four files? Or it takes all files on src directory? There is very old programs and we don't have any documentation

Comment: Most of this Makefile appears to be attempting to reproduce the default rules that Make will use if the Makefile didn't exist.  I would recommend deleting the file.

Comment: There's no rule that could create `$(EXECUTABLE)`, so I don't see how this Makefile should do *anything*

Comment: Please don't destroy the original question once you've received an answer.  Your secondary question probably can't be answered with the information available to us.  You've probably only shown a fragment of the makefile.  You've certainly not identified which 'four necessary files' are used or how the program is built.  From what's visible, you're likely to get messages about libraries being ignored when creating the object file.  There isn't a rule shown for building the executable, so it is likely to be built from a single source file — unless missing material says otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

`.c.o:` declares a simple *pattern rule* that matches any file ending with `.c` and defines the same name, but with `.o` as the target.

`$*` is an automatic make variable and expands to the matched part of the pattern. If it matched `main.c`, `$*` will be `main`.

`$<` is an automatic make variable as well, containing the name of the first prerequisite (so, for example `main.c`). With `:xx=yy`, you can replace strings at the end of a variable in make, so `${<:.c=.o}` transforms `main.c` to `main.o`.

---

That explained, the syntax is weird and unnecessary. The canonical way to write such a rule is:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o$@ $<
```

or, for a `make` that doesn't have this kind of pattern rules

```
.SUFFIXES: .c .o

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o$@ $<
```

Comment: my questions: on the src directory I have 20 files *.c, but the makefile has to compile only 4 files sec2dte_mq.c, sec2dte_2ici.c,adt.c,dte_mq.c. How it can find them among all others? Or it compiles all , independ we need them or not

Comment: This has nothing to do with the rules you showed. If only 4 files are needed, there's probably a rule somewhere linking these 4 object files. `make` is all about "doing what's needed" to produce one final target. If nothing depends on any other `.o` files, `make` will not apply this rule, just because it finds some matching prerequisites.

Comment: ,I will update my post to put complete makefile, please try to explain me where are those four files mentioned

Comment: please look at the file now